# How do i undefine a function previously defined in a library in vs2008

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I am using vs2008 and DDK 2003 to build a solution. A .cpp file has a definition of a function which is already defined in a library eh.lib. While building the solution it always gives me a warning as -

'public: const char* typename::name(void) const already defined in eh.lib(typname.obj); second definition ignored;'

Now i want this function to be redefined how can i do this.
The class type_info is declared in a header file 'typeinfo' which is provided by vs2008. I have included the header file too. Here is that part of the code-

```
#include <typeinfo>
const char* type_info::name() const
{
    return raw_name();
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to replace the [`std::type_info`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_info) structure? That's not allowed. With very few exceptions you can not do anything in the `std` namespace, and attempting to do so will lead to *undefined behavior*.

Comment: No i am not trying to edit std::type_info. In visual studio there is a header file named typeinfo.h which has a class called type_info. This is what i am trying to define but the warning says it has already been defined in eh.lib and so this definition has been ignored.

Comment: `<typeinfo` or `<typeinfo.h>`? And *why* do you want to do this? What is the use-case? This has the smell of an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).